# mysql how to make a query through bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

How to make a mysql statement or query through bash script?? for example create a user and a database??
i'm trying through a bash script to run a simple mysql statement

```
echo "insert database name"
read $db
echo "insert username "
read varname
echo "insert password for the user "
read -s varpass

sudo mysql -u root  -e <<EOF
CREATE DATABASE $db;
CREATE USER '$varname'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$varpass';
GRANT ALL ON $db.* TO '$varname'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$varpass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT;
EOF
```

Comment: Did you find the answer below useful @ayucaba?

Comment: Yes was a mistake made up by doing fast instead of thinking, thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped. You are welcome to use this method to accept an answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

`test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "insert database name"
read db
echo "insert username "
read varname
echo "insert password for the user "
read -s varpass

sudo mysql -u root mysql<<EOF
CREATE DATABASE $db;
CREATE USER '$varname'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$varpass';
GRANT ALL ON $db.* TO '$varname'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
\q
EOF
```

Note the changes:

- `read $db` was changed to `read db` - the `$` was removed
- Database name was added before `<<EOF`
- Exit was replaced with \q

**What if your database had a password**

You could create a file `~/.my.cnf` with the following contents:

```
[client]
user=root
password=YourPassword123!!
```

Then, you can log on to mysql's `mysql` database using the command `mysql mysql`. Using that, you can change just the `<<EOF` line to:

```
mysql mysql<<EOF
```

Everything else can remain the same.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as your answer to put closure to your question. That way, when someone is looking for a question similar to yours, the accepted answer can help them. And great job putting the right amount of details in your question @ayucaba